# Counting the number of lines in a C++ program leaving comments

Tags: c++

I am self learner of C++. So far i managed to code a program which leaves single line comments and tells the total lines in a program. How to leave multiple line comments also.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
//#include<conio.h>
#include<string>
using namespace std;

int main () {
    char c[100];
    string path;
    int num=0;
    cout<<"Enter a file name";
    cin>>path;
    ifstream is;
    //cout<<"ennter the file to count the lines in file\n";
    is.open (path.c_str());
    try
    {
        if(!is)
        {
            throw 1;
        }
    }
    catch(int a)
    {
        cout<<"Cannot open file";
    }
    if(is)
    {
        while (is.good())
        {
            is.getline(c,100);
            if (c[0]!='\\')
                num++;  
        }
        is.close();
        cout<<"Number of lines in file is "<<num<<endl;
    }
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your text format apparently uses `\\` in column 0 for single-line comments. What do you use for multi-line comments?

Comment: I completely fail to see the point of throwing 1 and catching it two lines later. You're also assuming the input succeeds and `c` has valid characters when you check `c[0]`.

Comment: Please indent your code properly so others can read it.

Comment: C++ is extremely complex to parse if you want to do it correctly. Your best bet is to use other existing tools to strip comments. You can invoke the "C pre processor" to strip comments. You can then make your code count the number of non empty lines left.

Comment: If you have working code and wanted it reviewed for best practice and help on improvement then post here: http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: If you really only want to count the number of code lines (not something else!) then it's actually a quite easy task that can be done with an extremely simple scanner. Though it gets slightly more complicated if you consider nested comments. Those are of course forbidden, but nothing prevents people from writing them anyway (most compilers don't even warn). Tip: Instead of reading "lines", try reading "characters", and remember the last one seen. Then the code becomes trivial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

finally i made it to work 
now i am counting braces also

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;
ifstream is;
void lines();
void braces();
int main () 
{
int choice=0;
string path;
cout<<"Enter a file name to count  :";
cin>>path;
is.open (path.c_str());
if(is)
{
cout<<"1.No of lines\n2.Total No of lines excluding braces\nEnter your choice:";
cin>>choice;
switch(choice)
{
case 1:
    lines();
    break;
case 2:
    braces();
    break;
default:
    cout<<"Invalid selection";
}
}
else
{
    cout<<"Invalid path";
}
system("pause");
return 1;
}
void lines()
{
string tmp;
size_t cno=0;
int num=0;
while (is.good())
{
    getline(is,tmp);
    if((tmp.find("/*")==0))
    {
        cno=tmp.find("*/");
        while(cno==-1)
        {
        getline(is,tmp);
        cno=tmp.find("*/");
        }
    }
    else if((tmp.find("//")==0))
    {
    }
    else
    {   num++;
    }
}
    is.close();
    cout<<"Number of lines in file is "<<num<<endl; 
}
void braces()
{
string tmp;
size_t cno=0;
int num=0;
while (is.good())
{
    getline(is,tmp);
    if((tmp.find("/*")==0))
    {
        cno=tmp.find("*/");
        while(cno==-1)
        {
        getline(is,tmp);
        cno=tmp.find("*/");
        }
    }
    else if((tmp.find("//")==0))
    {
    }
    else if((tmp.find("{")!=-1&&tmp.find("}")!=-1))
    {   num++;
    }
    else if((tmp.find("{")!=-1||tmp.find("}")!=-1))
    {}
    else
        num++;
}
cout<<"Number of lines without braces is:"<<num<<endl;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You may use an if-clause to check a line whether it contains "/*". In case you find a match you ignore all the lines until you reach "*/".
See if you can figure out the code for this by yourself. If you run into problems, show us what you tried and we can help you from there.

Comment: Its not as simple as that what about: `std::string line("Hi /*");`

Comment: Well, you must not check just the beginning of a line but the whole.

Comment: A solution covering every case will be complex, absolutely. But that problem is not C++-specific but a problem to differentiate the symbols to use for comments in strings and comments in general. By checking for /* and */ you should be able to cover pretty much, nevertheless. Or do I miss something else completely?

Answer (score 0):

In C++ you can use std::find to check if there'is an occurence of the string "/*" or "//".
In the first case, you can skip all the lines until the string "*/".

Another solution is to call directly a script, if you are working on linux as I hope!

```
int main() {
  const int rows = system("countRows.sh");
  ...
}
```

Where your script **countRows.sh** is:

```
#!/bin/bash
 wc -l foo.cpp | cut -f1 -d' '
```

The command gives you ALL row in file, you have to implement the filter!

Comment: -1 because essentially, to a question asking "how do I do this in C++?", your answer is "don't use C++".

Comment: In fact "another solution"

Comment: @hvd: PArt of programming is learning the correct tools to do the job. C++ is not the correct tool for this job.

Comment: thanks Loki. By the way I add the C++ solution (no, isn't the same of Tim, he didn't check for "//")

Comment: @LokiAstari Why not? It's a perfectly good tool here, and the utilities that would be called from the script are typically written in C. Downvote removed by the way, considering the edit.